# Need to write arabic text inside table cell in header of PDF using Lowagie implementation of iText

Tags: java, itext

We have been requested by a customer to create a table with some fields and value in the header of PDF that is been generated. This header needs to be repeated.

Earlier implementation had the data in PDFPTable and PDFPCell in the body content and failed to get repeated even after a lot of attempts. We have moved from PDFPTable --> Table and PDFPCell --> Cell and it worked in the header. Now one of the columns of the table contains Arabic text and there is no option of RUNDIRECTION setting RTL in simple Table and Cell. The text written in Unicode is wrongly printed. Any help is appreciated. Source code specified for reference IS SAMPLE and doesn't contain complete processing.

```
public class DataReportFiller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ff.setFileType(FileFormat.FILE_TYPE_PDF);
        PDFWriter pw = new PDFWriter(ff, basePath);

        pw.open(fileName, recordSize);
        Document document = pw.getDocument();
        document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);

        pw.openFileForHeader();

        String accStr10[] = null;

        accStr10 = new String[] { "TESTING DATA", "", "", "", "", "",
                "Total Pages ", Integer.toString(totalPages), "", "",
                "\u0629\u062d\u0641\u0635\u0644\u0627 \u0645\u0642\u0631", "" };

        pw.setBorder = false;
        pw.setBold = true;
        pw.fontColour = PDFWriter.COLOUR_BLACK;
        pw.bgColour = PDFWriter.COLOUR_WHITE;
        pw.horAlignment = pw.ALIGN_LEFT;

        // ----------------------------------
        int totalPages = 1;
        totalPages = totalPages + ((recordSize + 5) / 12);

        Table headerTable = pw.getHeaderTable();
        headerTable.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
        headerTable.setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
        pw.writeStatementHeaderLine(accStr10, DataWriter.LINE_TYPE_GENERAL);
        headerPhrase.add(2, headerTable);

        HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(headerPhrase, false);
        header.setAlignment(0);
        header.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        document.setHeader(header);
        pw.openFile();

        pw.createEmptyLine();
        pw.commitEmptyLine();

        pw.close();

    }

    // Another method to write data in header, unable to put arabic text here
    public boolean writeStatementHeaderLine(String line[], int type)
            throws Exception {
        try {

            // Increment the current line number
            currentLineNo++;

            // Check if the text is not null or empty
            if (line == null || line.length == 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < fileFormat.getFileColCount(); i++) {
                    chunk = new Chunk(" ", font);
                    Cell simpleCell = new Cell(new Phrase(chunk));
                    headerTable.addCell(simpleCell);
                }

                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
                setFont();

                Cell simpleCell = null;
                if (line[i] == null) {
                    chunk = new Chunk("", font);
                    simpleCell = new Cell(new Phrase(chunk));
                } else if ((type == LINE_TYPE_GENERAL && i >= line.length - 2)) {
                    final String FONT = applicationContext
                            .getProperty("arabic.font.path");
                    font = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
                            BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 8);
                    if (line[i].equalsIgnoreCase("iban"))
                        setFont();
                    chunk = new Chunk(line[i], font);
                    simpleCell = new Cell(new Phrase(chunk));

                } else {
                    chunk = new Chunk(line[i], font);
                    if (type == LINE_TYPE_GENERAL) {
                        simpleCell = new Cell(new Phrase(chunk));
                    }

                }
                simpleCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

                if ((type == LINE_TYPE_GENERAL && i >= line.length - 2)) {
                    simpleCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                    // simpleCell.rotate();

                }
                headerTable.addCell(simpleCell);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            deleteFile();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Requires to print branch as "فرع شجرة" in PDF header table, where it is displaying "عرفلا".

Comment: Have you already tried it with iText 7 + the pdfCalligraph add-on? iText 2 may just not be able to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately it is part of large scale implementation and bringing in iText 7 is challenging and since this is part of product implementation we're stuck with no upgrades. Though POC on iText 7 succeeded, but we're left to do with current library. Any suggestions are well appreciated.

Comment: `there is no option of RUNDIRECTION setting RTL in simple Table and Cell.` there is a way, I will share the code shortly. I have generated a table where my data columns have Arabic in them

Comment: Ok Danyal..is that part of header table? We're trying the options of manipulating margin with body content table by then. Looking forward to your snippet share.

Answer (score 0):

**This was finnaly achieved by using onEndPage method of PageEvent, code provided below for reference**

pw.openFile();

```
        pw.writer.setPageEvent(new PdfPageEventHelper(){


            protected ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContext.getInstance();




            @Override
            public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
            {


                PdfPTable table1=new PdfPTable(12);
                try{


                String accStr[] = null;
                String accStr10[] = null;

                accStr = new String[] { accountTitle ,"","","","","","Period Covered " ,startDate +" to " +endDate,"","","\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u063a\u0637\u064a\u0629",""};
                accStr10 = new String[] {address1 ,"","","","","","Page No ",Integer.toString(writer.getPageNumber()-1),"","","\u0631\u0642\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0635\u0641\u062d\u0629",""};

                table1.setTotalWidth(522);
                float f[] = {45,10,0,0,0,0,25,35,0,0,20,0};
                table1.setWidths(f);

                pw.setBorder = true;
                pw.setBold = true;
                pw.fontColour = AccStmtPDFWriter.COLOUR_BLACK;
                pw.bgColour = AccStmtPDFWriter.COLOUR_WHITE;
                pw.horAlignment = pw.ALIGN_LEFT;
                PdfPCell pdfCell=null;

                //table1=pw.getTable1();



                if(!FieldNameUtil.isApplicableForBahrain){
                    pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("")));
                    pdfCell.setBorder(0);
                    pdfCell.setColspan(12);             
                    table1.addCell(pdfCell);
                    table1=writeHeaderLine(accStr, DataWriter.LINE_TYPE_GENERAL,table1);
                    }

                    pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("")));
                    pdfCell.setBorder(0);
                    pdfCell.setColspan(12);             
                    table1.addCell(pdfCell);
                    table1=writeHeaderLine(accStr10, DataWriter.LINE_TYPE_GENERAL,table1);


                table1.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 57, 730, writer.getDirectContent());
                //document.add(table1);
                table1.deleteBodyRows();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            public PdfPTable writeHeaderLine(String line[], int type,PdfPTable table2)
                    throws Exception {
                Chunk chunk = null;
                PdfPCell cell =null;
                PdfPTable tableNew =table2;
                Font font=FontFactory.getFont("Arial",8,Font.BOLD,Color.BLACK);
                try {



                    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
                        //changed by shruti
                        if (line[i] == null)
                            chunk = new Chunk("", font);
                        else if(type==115 || (type==pw.LINE_TYPE_GENERAL && i>=line.length-2) || (type==112 && i==line.length-1)){  
                            final String FONT = applicationContext.getProperty("arabic.font.path");
                            font = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED,8);
                            if(line[i].equalsIgnoreCase("iban"))
                                font=FontFactory.getFont("Arial",8,Font.BOLD,Color.BLACK);
                            chunk = new Chunk(line[i], font);
                        }else
                            chunk = new Chunk(line[i], font);

                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(chunk));
                        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                        cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM); 
                        if((type==pw.LINE_TYPE_GENERAL && i>=line.length-2)){
                            cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
                            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                            tableNew.addCell(cell);
                        }else{
                            tableNew.addCell(cell);
                        }

                    }

                    return tableNew;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw e;
                }
                }




        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be not a full solution but There is a utility that may help you very much. There is an Open Source java library (written by me) called MgntUtils that has the utility that converts any String to unicode sequence and vise-versa. All you will have to do is:

```
String codes = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("Hello world");
```

And it will return String `"\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064"`

The same would work for any String in any language including special characters. Here is the link to the article [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/) that explains about the library and where to get it (available both on [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.michaelgantman%7CMgntUtils%7C1.5.0.2%7Cjar) and [github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt). In the article search for paragraph: **"String Unicode converter"**.